# How to stop recompiling an extern crate in Rust

Tags: rust

I have a local dependency on some SDK. I make use of

```
extern crate local_sdk; 
use local_sdk::foo;
```

to use the `local_sdk` in my implementation.

I am making use of cargo to build. While building, the logs print the following at some stage -

> Compiling local_sdk v0.1.0 (file:///project/project-core/sdk/rust)

This happens even though I have already compiled the `local_sdk` earlier.
How do I prevent recompiling the `local_sdk` ? It consumes some significant time.

Contents of the my `Cargo.toml`:

```
[package]
name = "service"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Rajeev"]

[dependencies]
local_sdk = { path = "../../sdk/rust" }
```

The `local_sdk` has the following `Cargo.toml`:

```
[package]
name = "local_sdk"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Rajeev"]

[dependencies]
hex = "0.3"
protobuf="2.0"
rand = "0.4.2"
zmq = { git = "https://github.com/erickt/rust-zmq", branch = "release/v0.8" }
uuid = { version = "0.5", features = ["v4"] }
log = "0.3"
libc = "0.2"
ctrlc = { version = "3.0", features = ["termination"] }

[dev-dependencies]
env_logger = "0.3"

[build-dependencies]
cc = "1.0"
glob = "0.2"
```

Comment: Could you please provide a [MCVE] (meaning: the complete folder structure and the content of the two `Cargo.toml`s and of the Rust source files)? That would help a lot finding the problem in your setup! Thanks!

Comment: You've got two packages with the exact same name.  Does it still happen if you give them different names?

Comment: Sorry for that @DK. Updated the code now. The packages are infact different.

Comment: Are you working on a network drive/mount? (wild idea™)

Comment: No. Its a normal Ubuntu desktop.

Comment: What is the version of rust you are using?

Comment: Rust versino is 1.25

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using it, there was [an issue with RLS that was causing unnecessary rebuilds.](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rls/issues/803)

This issue has been fixed, to get the latest version of RLS, use

```
$ rustup update
```

Comment: No that isn't solving my problem.

Comment: I am using `--release` with `cargo build` . Would that be affecting anyhow?

Comment: No, even with `--release` it shouldn't rebuild everything, however unless you _are_ readying your code for release, I'd avoid that flag as it takes longer to build (optimising) and removes useful debug information.

Comment: Is there anything else that could be affecting the `target` directory?