Rust: Recompiling loaded crate all the time
With two crates I used I had this issue.
Right now the one I work  with is SQLX with "SQLITE" option. So I uses it as an example.
My system works perfectly well with many other crates. I tried another computer and the issue can be reproduced.
But here, it did work "normal" for some days and suddenly the issue started and from that on it stays.
The system is Windows 10 and the current stable versions of VSCo9de, Rust and RustAnalyzer. I try to work with a rather short "sqlx-test" testing program just in main.rs.
The issue is that when I e.g. change a single character in my source, RustAnalyzjer starts running for half a Minute blocking the compiler in case I do "cargo c",
When I do "cargo c", "cargo b" or "cargo r", not only my code is checked, but also one or more source file from the "SQLX" family are checked / recompiled.
   Compiling libsqlite3-sys v0.30.1
   Compiling sqlx-sqlite v0.8.2
   Compiling sqlx-macros-core v0.8.2
   Compiling sqlx-macros v0.8.2
   Compiling sqlx v0.8.2
   Compiling sqlx_test v0.1.0`

When I do "cargo b --verbose", I see
Running C:\Users\Michael Schnell\.rustup\toolchains\nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\bin\rustc.exe 
--crate-name libsqlite3_sys --edition=2021 'C:\Users\Michael Schnell\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\libsqlite3-sys-0.30.1\src/lib.rs' 
--error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts,future-incompat 
--diagnostic-width=207 --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link 
-C embed-bitcode=no -C debuginfo=2 --cfg 'feature="bundled"' --cfg 'feature="bundled_bindings"' --cfg 'feature="cc"' 
--cfg 'feature="pkg-config"' --cfg 'feature="unlock_notify"' --cfg 'feature="vcpkg"' 
--check-cfg 'cfg(docsrs)' --check-cfg 'cfg(feature, values("bindgen", 
"buildtime_bindgen", "bundled", "bundled-sqlcipher", 
"bundled-sqlcipher-vendored-openssl", "bundled-windows", "bundled_bindings", 
"cc", "default", "in_gecko", "loadable_extension", "min_sqlite_version_3_14_0", 
"openssl-sys", "pkg-config", "prettyplease", "preupdate_hook", "quote", 
"session", "sqlcipher", "syn", "unlock_notify", "vcpkg", "wasm32-wasi-vfs", "with-asan"))' 
-C metadata=0cef50ebc9aa4cbf -C extra-filename=-0cef50ebc9aa4cbf 
--out-dir 'C:\Users\Michael Schnell\rusttest\sqlx_test\target\debug\deps' -L 'dependency=C:\Users\Michael Schnell\rusttest\sqlx_test\target\debug\deps' --cap-lints allow 
-L 'native=C:\Users\Michael Schnell\rusttest\sqlx_test\target\debug\build\libsqlite3-sys-9d65fba1316fdd3c\out' -l static=sqlite3

Dirty sqlx-sqlite v0.8.2: the dependency libsqlite3_sys was rebuilt`

So the cause supposedly is that the date of sqlx-sqlite has changed. The location of the lib.rts file also is given in the output.
But the date of all "\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\sqlx-sqlite-0.8.2\src\*.rs" files is 7/24/2006  ?????
And there is no file libsqlite3_sys.* on my system.
Due to the compiling latency it's extremely hard to work on that project.
How to proceed ?
==================
I Searched for similar issues in the internet
I Nail down the lowest problem level I could find out (see above)
I read -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50734058/how-to-stop-recompiling-an-extern-crate-in-rust but they say This issue has been fixed, to get the latest version of RLS use rustup -update, which of course I already did.

Is it possible that your rust-analyzer has a different configuration than your local terminal would? (likely culprits are rustflags) If you disable rust-analyzer and just do terminal commands, do you still have the issue?

Your verbose log shows that it rebuilds sqlx-sqlite because libsqlite3-sys was rebuilt (and not due to file timestamps at least not from what you show). Presumably some line above would indicate why libsqlite3-sys was rebuilt; that's what you should post.

I had a similar issue recently, also with VSCode + Windows. It seems the build config used by rust-analyzer conflicts with the one used by cargo. I didn't get to the bottom of why this happens, but instead made rust-analyzer use a different directory for its builds.
To achieved this, I added the following configuration for my project's workspace, in .vscode/settings.json.
{
    "rust-analyzer.checkOnSave": true,
    "rust-analyzer.check.extraArgs": [
        "--target-dir", "${workspaceFolder}/target/check"
    ]
}

This will cause the rust-analyzer build to go to /target/check while cargo build will continue in /target, stopping them from conflicting with each other.

Thanks a lot for your fast answer !!
Where to put those lines ?

I put those lines in C:\Users\Michael Schnell\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json and it does work .
Excellent !

Seems like a shortcoming of the rust.analyzer.
Hoping for improvement (already tested the pre-release with no success)

@MichaelSchnell If this solves your issue it is not from a "shortcoming" in rust-analyzer but from a configuration mismatch; using a different version won't solve anything. Some follow-up questions to narrow down what could be the source. What Rust channel are you using and are you using an override? Are you using a workspace? Do you have a .cargo/config.toml configuration file? Do you have any other rust-analyzer.* properties in your VS Code settings?

Though sometimes mismatches in configuration are intentional in which case setting a different target directory (this answer) is the correct solution.

OK. I can't analyze this further. as I don't understand the role of the libsqlite3_sys thingy that does not seem to be a source file.
The first answer suggested that this might be a Windows only issue. I did not test Linux on that behalf yet. So I had the impression of this might be a "shortcoming".
Of course not using different directories would be an advantage as well with disk space usage, as with response time (as the files created by one "cargo check" could be used by the other.

I did use an "out of the box" configuration with weekly doing "rustup update", currently using the "stable" compiler.

@MichaelSchnell, I added the configuration to .vscode/settings.json in the project directory. I updated the post with the information.

Thanks !
Lazy me did not yet learn how to deal with workspaces :(

Creating a .vscode directory in the project folder and adding a settings.json file to it with the content above will do the trick (workspace is just the project directory)

Ah thanks. My original try did the setting for all projects. I'm not sure if this is appropriate :)

Yep the trick works perfectly.
Nonetheless it seems like a workaround
it would be great to find out what f this libsqlite3_sys thingy is and why it introduces this issue.

There are several sqlite3_sys*.d files, but seemingly no source for them. But there are build-scripts_build_ccb*.exe applications in libsqlite3-sys* folders ....
The build system seemingly can't appropriately deal with this.

I finally found several (huge) sqlite3.c source files in the crates.io downloads....

seemingly the sqlite3... stuff is "pulled" by the "sqlite" feature I requested in the sqlx dependency  in cargo.toml .
